# unable to update controller model value from custom directive with controller as syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I am facing problem to update my model values from custom directive using controller as syntax. I can clearly see that through console.log that the  values are getting changed in the directive however they are not getting updated in the controller.   `<h4>{{self.tabs}} </h4>` always shows same values.

In addition I want to do watch on controller (self --> tabs) model to add 'active class' but when I try to use watch it is throwing me out error. So I have commented that part. The following is the watch related code, which is not working:

```
$scope.$watch('tabsCtrlself.tabs.index', function() {
          if (tabsCtrlself.tabs.index === index) {
            angular.element($element).addClass('active');
          }
        });
```

Please find my  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fN6tuOrIUNXSYXiIFVO4?p=preview), Can any one direct me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use 'ng-class' attribute,eg:
<en-tab data-pane="myPaneName1" ng-class="{active:index==1}">Tab #1</en-tab>
<en-tab data-pane="myPaneName2" ng-class="{active:index==2}" >Tab #2</en-tab>
<en-tab data-pane="myPaneName3"  ng-class="{active:index==3}">Tab #3</en-tab>
'index' is a object in angular: $scope.index, initializes its value:
 $scope.index=1;
The first item is selected by default.

I think the object of 'tabsCtrl.tabs.index' is not a angular object, so can't auto refresh
```

Comment: That is fine. But what I am looking is understand the directives internals and add 'addClass('active')' from directive for the selected tab. We can even use 'data-selected="true" ' for that purpose. But I need to add active class from the directive.